# Twistor theory?

Tags: twistor

There is a great deal of basic information available about String Theory, but very little about alternative theories such as [Twistor theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twistor_theory). Can anyone give me, in layman's terms, an idea of the basic premise of Twistor theory and how it works?

Comment: Twistor theory is arcane even by the standards of theoretical physics. I have never seen a layman's guide that made sense and I don't expect ever to see such a thing. The nearest is chapter 33 in Penrose's book [The Road To Reality](http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Road-To-Reality-Complete/dp/0099440687), but even that will make little sense unless you know a fair bit of maths.

Answer (score 1):

Expecting ready-made answers kills the entire fun of learning something on your own and seeing it yourself. The `kick' that you get when you figure things out for yourself, without having anything to prove or show off to anyone, is parallel to none.

``Introduction to Twistor Theory'' - Hugett, Tod,  is perhaps the most sane reference for this subject, available on date. That may be a personal opinion, but I prefer well-grounded textbooks who adopt a cautious approach towards introducing a discipline, rather than popular textbooks who try to win people over by making too many far-fetched statements and exaggerate the `premise' of a theory.

I hope, I'm sounding like a teacher and not a preacher in any way!! You are free to seek second opinions on this issue. Happy learning :)